Chai as promised not telling me where an error occured
When I define a test that fails using normal chai like so:
it("Should fail 1", async () => {
    expect(1).to.equal(2);
});


I get the following error:
         Should fail 1:

      AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 2
      + expected - actual

      -1
      +2
      
      at /home/myComputer/tests/myTest.ts:10:26
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (tests/myTest.ts:27:12)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/myTest.ts:45:33)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

I.e. the first line tells me my AssertionError comes from line 10 in myTest.ts.
When I try to test promises though, such as
it("my test 2", async () => {
    await expect(Promise.reject("test")).to.be.fulfilled;
});

I only get
         my test 2:
     AssertionError: expected promise to be fulfilled but it was rejected with 'test'

This is very annoying, as this error doesn't tell me anything about where in my test the error actually occured. How do I make it tell me where the error actually occured?
The way I import chai and chai-as-promised is like so in case that matters:
import chai from "chai";
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;


I suspect the stack trace is being generated at a step later than the statement in your test function. Even enabling chai.config.includeStack = true doesn't print the error message (see chaijs/chai#425).

^ That said, using standard async/await like this should print the expected line/col data. Is there a reason you can't use that pattern?

Unfortunately this doesn't work for rejected Promises:
it("should fail async", async () => {
 const error = await Promise.reject(new Error("Oops"));
 expect(error).to.equal("Oops");
});

This test should pass, since the error that's being thrown is what I expect. In practice, this doesn't reach the expect statement though and instead just throws in the line above it. This is why I used chai as promised.

Ideally I'd want to use chai as promised as it seems to be the standard for this situation, but if you know of a way to test for rejected promises as well that gives the stack trace for promises I'd accept it as an answer too.

^ @Ahri "This test should pass…": No, it shouldn't — an Error instance is not equal to a string, and an awaited promise which rejects creates an exception, so the expect statement is never reached. Perhaps you'll be interested in using an abstraction like the one demonstrated in this answer.

You should be able to see the line in error if you use chai.config.includeStack. Additionally, you need to chain off of the eventually property of chai-as-promised.
import chai from "chai";
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

chai.config.includeStack = true; // <--- Add this

const expect = chai.expect;

it("my test 2", async () => {
    // Add .eventually
    await expect(Promise.reject("test")).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
});

A run of this for me looks like this:
user@comp $ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha spec.js


  1) my test 2

  0 passing (5ms)
  1 failing

  1) my test 2:
     AssertionError: expected promise to be fulfilled but it was rejected with 'test'
      at assertIfNotNegated (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:68:19)
      at /Users/user/project/node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:101:17
      at async Context.<anonymous> (file:///Users/user/project/spec.js:11:5)


My package.json uses "type": "module".

Node v20.12.2
mocha v10.4.0
chai v4.4.1
chai-as-promised v7.1.1

